# While trying to change placeholder text, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type

I am trying to modify the placeholder text of a text field in Swift. However there is an error about "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." I am not sure why this would be nil.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance your `input` is not connected in interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is `UITextField!`. It's probably `nil`, which probably means you forgot to connect it in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have weak pointer I think you should use `?` and use it again to unwrap your variable.

`@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField?`

`input?.placeholder = "some text";`

But as someone already said, you probably haven't connected the IBOutlet.